# Add pixels to existing value

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to add 5 pixels to an items padding without losing its inherited padding.

```
li{padding: 10px;}
```

and ideally something like this would give me 15px padding on the li:

```
<li style="padding: +5px;">
```

Comment: Can you use javascript? Or better, jquery?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use jQuery then for example, to add 5px to `li`:

`$('li').css("padding", "+=5")`

http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties

> As of jQuery 1.6, .css() accepts relative values similar to
>   .animate(). Relative values are a string starting with += or -= to
>   increment or decrement the current value. For example, if an element's
>   padding-left was 10px, .css( "padding-left", "+=15" ) would result in
>   a total padding-left of 25px.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `:before` and `:after`, however this will be only from two sides "top and bottom" or "left and right".

I'll suggest you to add a `div` inside `li` and give padding additional padding to it.

Answer (score 0):

You would actually just change the overall value for that padding, like:

```
<li style="padding: 15px">
```

Note: This would only change the style for this one

If you are going to use this li a lot, instead of typing that line each time, you could do a class (if you are using css), for example

```
 .xtrapad { padding: 15px; }
```

Then on each li you want to do, in the html file, you would put:

```
<li class="xtrapad">
```

In this specific situation, it would not save a lot of time in comparison, however, you could use the xtrapad class on more than just the li, such as `<p class="xtrapad">`

Also, multiple classes can be made, so if you had other classes made, i.e. nomargins, strong, etc you could do: `<li class="xtrapad marginless strong">` and it would use everything in those classes.